# Git Ignore Pattern for XCode Build Directory

Tags: xcode, git

I am new to Git, and this is my first project using Git rather than SVN as my source control. I am working in XCode on an iPhone project. I want Git to ignore the build directory, which is in the root folder of the XCode project. I've found several other questions here and also found articles on google that provide examples on how to create the .gitignore file in the root directory and then add it to the Git repository to get the directory to be ignored.

Here are the steps I'm taking when setting up the repository:

1. Open Terminal and navigate to the root directory of the application
2. Call `git init` to initialize the repository
3. Call `git add .gitignore` to add the gitignore file
4. Call `git commit -m` to commit the gitignore file
5. Call `git status` to view the status of the repository

At this point, all of the other directories and files listed in my gitignore file are properly ignored except the build directory. Here is what my gitignore file looks like:

```
build/
.DS_Store
**/*.pbxuser
*.mode2v3
*.mode1v3
**/*.perspectivev*
```

I have tried ignoring the build directory using the following different entries with no success:

- build
- build/
- build/*

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`build/` or `build/*` should be enough to ignore the directory.
See also "[Difference between `.gitignore` rules with and without trailing slash like `/dir` and `/dir/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38559600/6309)"

The only reasons it could be still not ignored at this point if it:

- has somehow been added to the index and committed (which, according to your setup, shouldn't be the case)
- has a trailing space (`/build` ) in the `.gitignore` file rule, as in [this `.gitconfig`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8422152/6309), *before* Git 2.0 (Q2 2014).

Comment: This was the solution. I must have copied the build/ entry from another file and had some whitespace at the end. Thanks, and nice catch!

Comment: your link is broken. by trailing space you mean `/build ` and not `/build`

Comment: @mfaani Thank you for the feedback. I have found a new link to replace the obsolete one, but I also have updated the answer.