# Difference between .gitignore rules with and without trailing slash like /dir and /dir/

Tags: git, gitignore

Is there a difference between `/dir` and `/dir/` in the .gitignore file within a Git repository?

How are the following different?

```
/dir
/dir/
/dir/*
```

Comment: The accepted answer below incorrectly states that /dir/ and /dir/* are equivalent. See Victor's answer further down: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38559600/607219

Answer (score 127):

Yes, these rules are different.

- `/dir` will match a file, directory, link, anything named `dir`
- `/dir/` will match *only* a directory named `dir`
- `/dir/*` will match all files, directories and anything else inside
  a directory named `dir` (but not the `dir` directory itself).

`/dir`, `/dir/` and `/dir/*` are **NOT** equivalent. The difference
is very clear when using overriding rules, like the famous `!.gitkeep`
to get around the limitation of tracking empty directories. Suppose
the existence of the file `dir/.gitkeep`

- With `/dir` and `/dir/`, Git won't even look inside the directory
  so the `.gitkeep` won't be seen.
- With `/dir/*`, the file will be detected by Git and the directory
  will be kept if this `.gitkeep` is committed, because the rule
  doesn't apply to the directory itself, only to its contents.

**OBSERVATION:** All the rules mentioned above are anchored at the current directory
(the place where the `.gitignore` is), because of the `/` prefix.
Without the prefix, the rules would apply not only for that specific directory, but also for the sub-directories or everywhere in the repository,
if the `.gitignore` is located at the root level.

Comment: Does `dir/` match a symbolic link *to a directory* named `dir`? And if so has that behaviour changed across Git versions? It seems to match fine for everyone on my team except one colleague.

Comment: @0xbe5077ed, in theory the symbolic link is just a file, so `dir/` should not match it. I just test it here locally and, indeed, it doesn't match like expected. I'm using Git v2.10.0.

Comment: how about `dir` then

Comment: It's written there @LukAron, "..._Without the prefix, the rules would apply not only for that specific directory, but also for the sub-directories_...". If you have `dir` in your `.gitignore`, it'll match files, directories and symlinks named `dir`, located at any nested directory, starting from where the `.gitignore` is located.

Comment: @VictorSchröder  Oh, I miss that sentence. Sorry about that. Is this ever mentioned in git documentation?

Comment: "All the rules mentioned above are anchored at the current directory (the place where the .gitignore is), because of the / prefix." — For clarity they ARE anchored to the current directory, but not JUST because of the `/` prefix. It's because a `/` slash appears somewhere in the line.

Quoting from `.gitignore` documentation: 

"The pattern doc/frotz and /doc/frotz have the same effect in any .gitignore file. In other words, a leading slash is not relevant if there is already a middle slash in the pattern."

Comment: The leading slash is needed in the example above, given that the first ignored object is a single word, not a composed path. Also, it is considered good practice to use the leading slash to denote the anchoring to the current path. Without it, the author's intention is unclear and subject to interpretation. Introducing two ways of doing the same exact thing is something to be avoided, specially for configuration. If you want to anchor to the current directory, do your team a favor, be clear and use the leading slash.

Answer (score 34):

### The Patterns Have Different Meanings

According to the Pattern Format section of [gitignore(5)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html):

> - If the pattern ends with a slash, it is removed for the purpose of the following description, but it would only find a match with a directory. In other words, foo/ will match a directory foo and paths underneath it, but will not match a regular file or a symbolic link foo (this is consistent with the way how pathspec works in general in git).
> - If the pattern does not contain a slash /, git treats it as a shell glob pattern and checks for a match against the pathname relative to the location of the .gitignore file (relative to the toplevel of the work tree if not from a .gitignore file).

What this means is that "dir" can be a file, directory, or symbolic link, but "dir/" with a trailing slash will only match a directory. In most cases, the difference won't matter, but when it does, understanding the distinction can remove ambiguity from your .gitignore files.

Answer (score 7):

Git 2.23 (Q3 2019) attempts to revamp the description about slashes in gitignore patterns (used to indicate things like "anchored to this level only" and "only
matches directories")

[The documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1a58bad0144dedd59eeef29b7ba7791aed19106f/Documentation/gitignore.txt#L92-L113) now includes:

> - The slash '`/`' is used as the directory separator.
>     Separators may occur at the beginning, middle or end of the `.gitignore` search pattern.
> - If there is a separator at the beginning or middle (or both) of the pattern, then the pattern is relative to the directory level of the particular `.gitignore` file itself.
>     Otherwise the pattern may also match at any level below the `.gitignore` level.
> - If there is a separator at the end of the pattern then the pattern will only match directories, otherwise the pattern can match both files and directories.
> - For example, a pattern `doc/frotz/` matches `doc/frotz` directory, but not `a/doc/frotz` directory;
>     however `frotz/` matches `frotz` and `a/frotz` that is a directory (all paths are relative from the `.gitignore` file).
> - An asterisk "`*`" matches anything except a slash.
>     The character "`?`" matches any one character except "`/`".
>     The range notation, e.g. `[a-zA-Z]`, can be used to match one of the characters in a range.
>     See fnmatch(3) and the `FNM_PATHNAME` flag for a more detailed description.