# How to add subfolder to gitignore file?

Tags: github, gitignore

I have .gitignore in learning_python folder,

need to add .ipynb_checkpoints folder to .gitignore.

.ipynb folder location:

```
learning_python/python_crash_course/.ipynb_checkpoints/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add in your `.gitignore` at the top folder of the repositry:

```
.ipynb_checkpoint/
```

The [OP Jay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12387540/jay) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59703735/how-to-add-subfolder-to-gitignore-file/59703740?noredirect=1#comment105576475_59703740) using:

```
**/.ipynb_checkpoint/
```

It will ignore any `.ipynb_checkpoint/` subfolder.
See also "[Difference between `.gitignore` rules with and without trailing slash like `/dir` and `/dir/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38559600/6309)".

But you need first to remove that folder from the repo (it is is already tracked, adding it to `.gitignore` would have no effect)

```
git rm --cached -r python_crash_course/.ipynb_checkpoints
```

Check that it is working with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- path/to/.ipynb_checkpoint/aFile
```

---

Example:

```
D:\git>git clone https://github.com/r46j/learning_python
Cloning into 'learning_python'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 51, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (51/51), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (35/35), done.

Receiving objects: 100% (51/51), 16.19 KiB | 2.31 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (16/16), done.

D:\git>cd learning_python

D:\git\learning_python>cd python_crash_course
D:\git\learning_python\python_crash_course>mkdir .ipynb_checkpoint

D:\git\learning_python\python_crash_course>cd .ipynb_checkpoint

D:\git\learning_python\python_crash_course\.ipynb_checkpoint>echo ee>dummy

D:\git\learning_python\python_crash_course\.ipynb_checkpoint>cd ..\..
D:\git\learning_python>git check-ignore -v -- python_crash_course\.ipynb_checkpoint\dummy
.gitignore:1:.ipynb_checkpoint/ "python_crash_course\\.ipynb_checkpoint\\dummy"
```

If it does, add, commit (to record the deletion) and push.

Comment: I tried it, its not working.

https://github.com/r46j/learning_python

Comment: @Jay OK. I have edited my answer accordingly: it will work.

Comment: @Jay I have added an example to my answer, using your repo: it does work.

Comment: @Jay OK, well done! I have edited the answer accordingly.