# What is fastest way to .gitignore a directory: With or without trailing slash and **?

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to exclude the directory 'dir' from a git repo using .gitignore. No further exclude patterns shall refer to it with `!/dir...`, it shall only be mentioned once in the .gitignore.

Which of these alternatives is the fastest for git to apply and decide not to look further into the dir?

- `/dir`
- `/dir/`
- `/dir/*`
- `/dir/**`

The pattern matching is implemented in [git/dir.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/dir.c).
Relevant functions seem to be [match_pathspec_item](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4b6846d9dcd391164b72bd70e8a0c0e09776afe3/dir.c#L324), [do_match_pathspec](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4b6846d9dcd391164b72bd70e8a0c0e09776afe3/dir.c#L447), [prep_exclude](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4b6846d9dcd391164b72bd70e8a0c0e09776afe3/dir.c#L1535) and [treat_directory](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4b6846d9dcd391164b72bd70e8a0c0e09776afe3/dir.c#L1851).

Comment: Out of curiosity: is there any active performance issue that you're tracking or is this theoretical interest only? Because I can't imagine that this kind of difference makes *any* noticeable difference in a daily workflow. Which specific operations do you want to know the "performance" of?

Comment: This is only of theoretical interest.

Comment: The semantic differences are elaborated in https://stackoverflow.com/q/17888695

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you note indirectly, these aren't semantically equivalent since they act differently if `/dir` is a *file*.  However, if you somehow "know" that `/dir` will in fact *be* a directory, `/dir` and `/dir/` would be the "efficient" ways to list these as they will omit opening-and-reading the directory.

Whether `/dir/` is *less* efficient or *just as* efficient as `/dir` depends on your OS and its `readdir` implementation: when Git reads the directory `/` (the top of the working tree), it gets the name components `.`, `..`, `README.txt` (assuming there is such a file), `abc` (maybe a file, maybe a directory, we'll just assume there is something named `abc`), `dir` (a directory), and whatever else.  It *may* also get a useful `d_type` field: [POSIX only requires a `d_name` and `d_ino`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/basedefs/dirent.h.html), but Linux and the BSDs have a `d_type` field.  The OS will fill in `d_type` with one of:

- `DT_UNKNOWN`: we didn't tell you anything
- `DT_DIR`: this entity is for a directory
- `DT_REG`: this entity is for a regular file
- various other possibilities not listed here (see also [Checking if a dir. entry returned by readdir is a directory, link or file. dent->d_type isn't showing the type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23958040/1256452) and Git's [cache.h](https://github.com/git/git/blob/faa21c10d44184f616d391c158dcbb13b9c72ef3/cache.h#L45-L57)).

Git will use this value, if it's available.  If it *is* `DT_DIR`, Git will know that `dir` is a directory and won't need to call `lstat` on the path when deciding whether the `/dir/` entity matches.  If it is `DT_UNKNOWN`, Git won't know what kind of entity `dir` represents and *will* need to call `lstat`.  However, for the `/dir` anchored gitignore entry, Git doesn't *care* what kind of entity `dir` represents, so it definitely won't need to call `lstat`.  But maybe it doesn't need to call `lstat` anyway, so that this gains nothing.

(Should `/dir` name a *file* and you want Git to store that file if it exists, or complain about it as untracked as appropriate, you should use `/dir/` here and not worry about the cost of a single `lstat` system call, even though it may be measured in hundreds of microseconds, or even low-digit milliseconds, rather than nanoseconds.  But milliseconds *do* add up eventually, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want ignore a folder use:

`/folderName` => ignore folderName || fileName from root directory

`/folderName/` => ignore folderName from root directory

But if you `folderName/` ignore all folders with the name folderName. I would guess that that tokes more time because he iterate recursive over all folders from root upwards.

but in my opinion it doesn't matter. gitignore is not important for the programme and has no influence on the performance of the programm.

Comment: I know it practically doesn't matter, but I'm interested in the subtle differences anyway: Maybe one alternative only runs a loop once while another runs it 10 times. By the way, `/folderName` would also exclude a file with that name, not just the dir.